# What are you supposed to do after an OAuth2 call succeeds?

Tags: oauth-2.0

At work we have never used 3rd party Auth solutions and I'm trying to inform myself of how they work for my personal projects. Getting the response is easy enough, but feel a bit lost on what to do after I get the response back. Am I supposed to send the auth token to the backend so it can be verified then trigger my app's login process for the given e-mail address/username? Logging them in essentially without a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two basic use cases for OAuth 2.0 which will determine what you do after the user is authorized. Your use case can also determine which OAuth 2.0 permission scopes you request the user to authorize your app for.

## 1. Single Sign-on

A simple use case for using a 3rd party OAuth solution is to leverage the 3rd party to perform authentication. Two reasons for this include:

1. Your users may wish the convenience of logging in with another provider (like Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.), one where he or she may already have an active session.
2. You may not wish to implement your own login / authentication / password reset process.

Either way, a common way to implement this is to make an API request using the token to retrieve the user's email address after a successful authentication, which you then map to your own user database to establish an authenticated session for your service. Since you only need to retrieve the user's email address and minimal other information (e.g. name) in this use case, you can ask for a minimal set of scopes.

I do this in my [`oauth2more` library](https://github.com/grokify/oauth2more) where after receiving a token, I have a generic interface to load a user data which I convert to a SCIM user object. Because I've abstracted  the code to retrieve user info in this manner, it's easy to support SSO across mulitple auth providers.

## 2. Using Service Features

A slightly different use case is that you want the user to authorize your app so you can make commands on behalf of the user via API. In this case, you will use the token to call more general APIs to accomplish your goals. A caveat is that you will need to make sure you ask for the proper permissions when asking the user to authorize your app.

As an example, one thing I've done is ask the user to sign in with Google so I can then make API calls to create and edit Google Sheets and Google Slides using APIs on their behalf.